# How to change woocommerce Registration Successful text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, user-registration

When I register on My account page, I receive a message says: 
**"Registration successful! You will be notified upon approval of your account."**

How do I change this text?

I have searched around, and I was surprised that no one is searching for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update:**
>
> As it's a Wordpress notice, and it's generated most of the time with sprintf() function (partial text + variables), you can check if you get partially an extract of this sentence using [**`stripos()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) php function in the condition, this way:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_specific_text_in_woocommerce', 10, 2 );
function customizing_specific_text_in_woocommerce( $customized_text, $targeted_text, $domain )
{
    // Set Here an extract of the text to replace:
    $text_to_find = 'be notified upon approval of your account';

    if ( stripos( strtolower( $targeted_text ), '$text_to_find' ) !== false && is_account_page() ) {

        // Set here your replacement text.
        $customized_text = __('My custom text goes here.', $domain);
    }
    return $customized_text;
}
```

You will have to make different tries, to get it work...

---

This text is certainly part of your main theme customizations, that's why you haven't find any related problem on internet. You should try to use the [WordPress **`gettext`** filter hook function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext), this way *(without any guaranty, as I can't test it really)*:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customizing_specific_text_in_woocommerce', 10, 2 );
function customizing_specific_text_in_woocommerce( $customized_text, $targeted_text, $domain )
{
    // Set Here the text to replace:
    $text_to_find = 'Registration successful! You will be notified upon approval of your account.';

    if ( $text_to_find == $targeted_text && is_account_page() ) {

        // Set here your replacement text.
        $customized_text = __('My custom text goes here.', $domain);
    }
    return $customized_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

> This text is certainly a theme customization, and should be located in your main active parent theme files, in the woocommerce templates folder or in some other themes files.

Comment: Thanks. 
gettext works on the other content, but not the alert message.

Comment: @user3390591 You should update your question as it's not really clear, adding that is a WordPress notice… Because this kind of notice use sprintf()  function with variables, so that's why is not possible to target the all  entire text directly with **`get text `** add filter hook. So I have update my answer with an alternative that you can try (without any guaranty)… I hope it will work.

Comment: I still can't get it work. I can replace other text, but just couldn't replace the text in alert message. Leave this to me, I will try a few more tests. Many thanks

Comment: @user3390591 I think that this is a customization located in your parent  main theme files. You will have to look in them to find out how is the best solution to customize it for your own needs. Anyway thanks and good luck.